# How to use guzzle in Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I'm planning to use Guzzle to communicate with my XML web service.
I am able to communicate with my XML web service using core PHP 5.6. I want to do this within my Laravel App using Guzzle to communicate with XML web service.

My xml config code is as follows:

```
        $requestXmlBody  ='';
        $requestXmlBody  = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<FAB_PkgAvailRQ Target="test" Version="2002A" xmlns="https://localhost.com/find">';
        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<SyndicatorInfo SyndicatorId="******" SyndicatorPassword="*****"/>';
        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<SessionInfo CreateNewSession="true"/>';
        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<HolidaySearchRequest ResponseTimeoutSecs="60" ExcludeNonBookableSuppliers="true">';
        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<SearchCriteria FlightOnly="true" OneWayOnly="'.$journey_type.'" NumberOfAdults="'.$adults.'" NumberOfChildren="'.$children.'" NumberOfInfants="'.$infants.'">';

        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<DepartureDateRange StartDate="'.$from.'" EndDate="'.$from.'"/>';
        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<DepartureAirports><Airport>'.$origin.'</Airport></DepartureAirports>';
        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<DestinationChoice><DestinationAirports><Airport>'.$destination.'</Airport></DestinationAirports></DestinationChoice>';
        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<FlightPreferences/>';

        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<HolidayDuration MinNumberOfNights="'.$ddays.'" MaxNumberOfNights="'.$ddays.'"/>';
        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'</SearchCriteria>';
        // $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<ResultSetPreferences MaxItems="'.$numberofsearch.'" SortCode="cost" SortAscending="true"/>';
        // $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'<InitialViewInfo Length="'.$numberofsearch.'" Offset="0"/>';
        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'</HolidaySearchRequest>';
        $requestXmlBody = $requestXmlBody.'</FAB_PkgAvailRQ>';


       My curl code is as follows

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://localhost.com/23");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestXmlBody);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        $result1 = simplexml_load_string($result);
        dd($result1);
```

I want to send a POST request using Guzzle to above xml configuration to my xml web service such as paxport/multicom.
Any Idea How I can proceed?

Comment: Using Guzzle instead of curl is step one I would guess. [The quickstart guide](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html) can help. My guess is you need to [upload data](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#uploading-data)

Answer (score 3):

It's simple.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post('http://localhost.com/23', ['body' => $requestXmlBody]);

$result = $response->getBody()->getContents();

$result1 = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

Comment: Thanks..I will try and let you know

Comment: +"Warnings": SimpleXMLElement {#240 ▼
    +"Warning": array:2 [▼
      0 => "Error while invoking supplier service: com.amadeus.xml.AmadeusWebServicesBindingStub@5ed6eb8d"
      1 => "Supplier service returned an error: (401)Unauthorized"
    ]  I got this error while trying to post

Comment: Guzzle works fine. Add authorisation as described in the API documentation (I don't know what  API you are using). The error is exactly about that.

Comment: And one more question, how to display only a field instead of all data field using above guzzle. ??

Comment: It's not about Guzzle, it's about XML/JSON that you are receiving. Depends on how you work with the data.

Comment: Thanks.yeah i got it

Comment: Hi I got a problem, I wanted to use $result1 value in blade template. and I have multiple array values from response. How do you use for loop here. I tried old blade way like @foreach($result1 as $result) <p>{{ $result->id}} @endforeach .. But it loops throgh but doesn't display the value

Comment: Here is an example of using Guzzle right from the Laravel official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#refreshing-tokens
Just don't forget to add `use GuzzleHttp\Client;` or add a leading backslash to respect namespaces: `$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;`

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please find the answer here

add it to composer file

```
   "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
```

controller file

```
<?php 

/** add it at top **/
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException;
/*** end ***/
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as Controller;


class ApiController extends Controller {

function __construct() {
    $this->client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
}

 public function stockBatch($id) {

    $apiKey = 'xyx';
    $url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES&symbols=QQQ,AAPL&apikey=' . $apiKey;
    $response = $this->client->get($url);
    $results = $response->getBody();
    $results = json_decode($results);
    return response()->json($results);
}
}
```